# How to group mongoDb requests for better performance?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to group requests to MongoDb?

For example I have one collection.find and three collection.aggregate requests from C# code.

I'm wondering is there a way to combine them and send only one request through the network.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to. The amount of data sent through the network would be like 2kb, isn't that micro-optimisation?

Comment: However to answer the question, as I didn't in my last comment and I cannot edit it, no; as far as I know it is one call per operation. There is no SQL like multiquery.

Comment: thank you Sammaye,  MongoDb hosted on another server.  I don't want to save on amount of data but on calls...

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB's [wire protocol](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Wire+Protocol) is designed for a single operation per message, so there is no support for grouping multiple operations into a single request. The only thing that comes close to this is a [bulk insert](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Inserting#Inserting-Bulkinserts), but that's really one operation that takes multiple documents.

On a non-sharded MongoDB system, you could conceivably perform multiple server-side operations via a single [eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) command. This would entail sending MongoDB a JavaScript function that runs multiple operations and then stuffs their results into a single result to be returned. However, I'd be hard-pressed to think of a realistic situation where that'd be preferable to sending multiple requests via your driver (JS is less performant, there are concurrency issues, etc.).